# How to retrieve POST data from TbSelect2 widget in Yiibooster?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, yii

I am using the TBselect2 widget for Yiibooster. The code of my view is:

```
$this->widget(
        'bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2',
        array(
            'name' => 'cat_names',
            'data' => Category::getRecipe(),
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'multiple' => 'multiple',
                'class' => 'span3'
            )
        )
        );
```

The render output generates autocomplete input like "field" but when I inspect input field look alike box it is NOT an input field rather a div tag containing UL list with all the selected items.

After selecting the desired values from autocomplete box I have to POST the form but since HTML rendered by TBSelect2 is not input field, how do I get values generated by autocomplete TBSelect2 widget since it is not a form field?

P.S: This  is a long form containing multiple html elements,so I don't want to submit the form using Ajax.

Any help?

Comment: There should be a `<select>` also if you Inspect the elements you should see it below the input box.

Answer (score 2):

If you use developers tools in a browser you will see there is an input box and a select box. Your code should look something like this:

```
<div class="select2-container" id="s2id_options" style="width: 100%;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice select2-default" tabindex="-1">
        <span class="select2-chosen">Select or start typing name.</span>
        <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>
        <span class="select2-arrow"><b></b></span>
    </a>
    <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" id="s2id_autogen2">
</div>
<select name="cat_names" id="cat_names" tabindex="-1" class="select2-offscreen">
    //Your options
</select>
```

The select box `cat_names` will have the correct value in it on POST automatically. So if you look at `$_POST['cat_names']` it should have the value you selected in the Select2 input.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I am able to get the value in action method but it is not showing the correct values, like if I select 3 items in autocomplete box. In $_POST['cat_names'], I get 3 integer. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Those are probably the `values` in your `options`. For example look inside your `<select></select>`. Each option should look like this: `<option value='some_val'>This is what I display</option>` it sends what is in the `value` attribute just like any other select box.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to fill the field, submit the whole form and look, is there according value in request? Because when I try ["Loading data" example from docs](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), when I select the value, it's going into according hidden input.

Still, according to [Select2 documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#events)

> *change* event is triggered on the original element whenever its value is changed by the user

So, when user selects a value, there will be an event, and you can use that event to do whatever you want.